# SQLite floating point issue

Tags: sqlite, floating-point

This query returns 1.7763568394002505e-15 when it should return 0.00:

```
SELECT st.id
, Sum(
    CASE sa.Type 
    WHEN 4 THEN sa.quantity * (st.price - st.commission)
    WHEN 5 THEN -sa.quantity * (st.price - st.commission)
    ELSE 0.0 END
) Sales
FROM sales sa
JOIN stock st
  ON sa.stockid = st.id
WHERE st.id = 1
GROUP BY st.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cccd8/3

It's looks like a classic floating point calculation issue, but how can I fix it?
I've tried casting the various columns to REAL but it doesn't make a difference.

You can simulate the result using this query:

```
SELECT 26.3 - 10.52 - 15.78 AS Result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's REAL isn't suitable for currency. SQlite doesn't support SQL decimal or SQL numeric data types, so your best option is to use integer, and store values as cents.

```
CREATE TABLE stock (
  id INTEGER,
  -- Store price and commission as integers, implying that price is in cents,
  -- ($3.20 is stored as 320) and commission is a two-digit percentage (0.57%
  -- is stored as 57).  This is how scaled integers work in general.
  price integer,
  commission integer,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE sales (
  id INTEGER,
  stockid INTEGER,
  type INTEGER,
  quantity  INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

insert into stock values (1, 320, 57);
insert into sales values (1, 1, 4, 10);
insert into sales values (2, 1, 5, 4);
insert into sales values (3, 1, 5, 6);
```

This query, from your SQLfiddle, correctly returns 0.

```
SELECT st.id
, Sum(
    CASE sa.Type 
    WHEN 4 THEN sa.Quantity * (st.price - st.commission)
    WHEN 5 THEN -sa.Quantity * (st.price - st.commission)
    ELSE 0.0 END
) Sales
FROM sales sa
JOIN stock st
  ON sa.stockid = st.id
WHERE st.id = 1
GROUP BY st.id;
```

```
id          Sales
----------  ----------
1           0
```

Casting to a more appropriate data type (*not* to REAL) will *hide* some problems--maybe even most problems or even all of them in a particular application. But casting won't *solve* them, because stored values are liable to be different than the values you *really* want.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Sherrill is correct in that you probably should use integers. But for a quick-and-dirty fix, you can wrap the `Sum` call in a `Round(__,2)` to round to the nearest cent.